# Overpass Turbo Area Code Lookup

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am using [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu), with extended syntax to query places in an area, usually a country, using the following syntax

```
{{geocodeArea:CH}}->.searchArea;
(
   (node["place"]["name"~"^.+$"]["place"="country"](area.searchArea);)
);
out body;
```

Now, I would like to use this query against the open API directly.

I did figure out that it is possible but that the API is limited in regard to the extended syntax (the curly braces, it seems). So when I export the query from overpass turbo to `text` (Export -> Query -> Text), I get the following output:

```
area(3600051701)->.searchArea;
(
  (node["place"]["name"~"^.+$"]["place"="country"](area.searchArea);)
);
out body;
```

I can then POST this request to the API and it works.

**Now my question:**

I see that the text export converted the area code "CH" to the string/id `3600051701`.

Is it possible to have a lookup for these IDs? I might need to query many different countries and it would be convenient to have a lookup table somewhere.

I am new to OSM/Overpass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When searching for country areas instead of using `{{geocodeArea:CH}}` I found that this also works: `area["ISO3166-1"="CH"]`

To retrieve a list of IDs of country areas you can query

```
(
  area["ISO3166-1"="CH"];
  area["ISO3166-1"="DE"];
  area["ISO3166-1"="FR"];
  area["ISO3166-1"="NL"];
  area["ISO3166-1"="SP"];
  area["ISO3166-1"="RU"];
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

which will return something like the following, with all relevant tags attached:

```
  <area id="3600051477"/>
  <area id="3600051701"/>
  <area id="3600060189"/>
  <area id="3600062781"/>
  <area id="3602202162"/>
  <area id="3602323309"/>
```

A way to get all country area IDs is to query for `boundary=administrative` & `admin_level=2` (see the [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level)) in combination with the existence of the `ISO3166-1` tag:

```
area["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="2"]["ISO3166-1"];
out ids;
```

This results in 214 areas at this point. Leaving out the `ISO3166-1` tag results in a 391 results where there are a lot of duplicates and unwanted data. Some entries appeared to be Dutch islands, for example, which exist in addition to the main country Netherlands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this looks very interesting. I'll try it out tomorrow and will be back with feedback :)

Comment: So, I finally found time to test it, and it's working out very well. Especially what you are stating in the first sentence is saving me a lot troubles (and work :) ). Thanks for the answer @chrki, accepted!